# How to access iCloud file invitation

Tags: icloud, apple-id, system-settings, messages-in-icloud

An iCloud file was shared with my apple id and a friend's apple id.  However, we're both new to iCloud and neither of us have been able to access the file.

The file was definitely shared: the person who shared it sent the following screenshot (redaction mine):
[image]

Here is what I see when I log into iCloud Drive:

[image]

Both folders are empty.

Accessing iCloud through System Preferences yields no clues either.  Where should I be looking for this shared file?

Comment: Have you clicked the link he sent you?  If so, what happens?

Comment: I never got one, and neither did my friend.  Not in spam or anything.  Gmail search for 'iCloud' yields nothing relevant.

Comment: You need to click the link to get access. See [this Apple doc](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-files-with-icloud-file-sharing-mchl91854a7a/mac) for details.  Your friend has to send you the link first.